# click() method not working properly in isolated environment

Tags: puppeteer

We have 2 puppeteer suites: first "isolated" (so just the UI, without backend) and second with service(s) connected.
With the latter this works

```
 await testPage.click('.button-class');
```

But it's not working in the first isolated one, so we're using:

```
 await testPage.evaluate(() => {
                const button = document.querySelector('.button-class');
                button.click();
            })
```

which works fine.

First, I thought it might have something to do with `waitUntil` option in `goto()` method, but tried all the different values and also without this option defined and the result was the same: click() doesn't work.

Also, in isolation this element is undefined and with backend it's logging some ElementHandle.

Comment: Have you tried using  `await testPage.waitForSelector('.button-class');` before trying the click ?

Comment: @Rippo yes and also waitForTimeout

Answer (score 0):

Looks like adding `--no-sandbox` flag to `launchOptions` args fixed this.